# registerForRemoteNotificationTypes with quickblox in IOS8

Tags: ios8, quickblox

I'm trying subscribe for push notifications using:

```
//QBMessages
+ (NSObject<Cancelable> *)TRegisterSubscriptionWithDelegate:(NSObject<QBActionStatusDelegate> *)delegate;
```

and getting that error:

> 2014-08-12 20:10:02.147 DemoApp[691:137189]
>   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and
>   later.

Any ideas how subscribe for push notifications in IOS8 with Quickblox?

Comment: QuickBlox will release a new iOS SDK this week which also will contain updates for this case

Comment: I hope it won't be exclusive call as it was before because often app can receive pushes from different services and update deviceToken to multiple locations during launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out QuickBlox iOS SDK 2.0
http://quickblox.com/blog/quickblox-releases-ios-sdk-2-0/

and new Push Notifications sample http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios which supports iOS8 as well